# Dart (Flutter) Future

Tags: dart

I need to know whether or not the file exists in the folder, but I get an instance of `Future<bool>`, how do I get the `false` or `true`?

```
for (String curFile in splittedList){
  Future<bool> t2 = Future.value(File(curFile).exists());
  print("$curFile - $t2");
}
```

result

```
I/flutter (16852): assets/images/Symbol/4.svg - Instance of 'Future<bool>'
```

Answer (score 0):

`var t2 = await File('...').exists()`

hope it helpful.

EDIT -----

try this

```dart
  Future<bool> checkAssets(String key) async {
    bool result = true;
    try {
      await rootBundle.load(key);
    } catch (e) {
      result = false;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Is there any way without using await? final t2 = File(curFile).existsSync();
      print("$curFile - $t2"); only return false

Comment: test(String path) async {
    var result = await File(path).exists();
    print("$path - $result");
    return result;
  } return only false

Comment: I edited the answer. pls try and see if it works. I didnt found any documentation but File usually be used to load files in device, not project dir.

Comment: It didn't work, I'm using the same path I put in pubspec.yaml, assets/images/Symbol/g.svg, is there another way to find it on the device?